# WordPress & PHP Dynamic Sub Page for Vcard download

Tags: php, wordpress, vcf-vcard

I'm looking to create a custom vcard URL for a custom post type and am currently unsure if it's possible and/or the best way to go about it.

I'd like the URL to be: **domain.co.uk/our-team/daniel-vickers/vcard**

However, as I'm using WordPress going to such a page will force the 404 page to appear, is it either possible to create this as a pure PHP page following this template URL structure as there would be many team members?

Or would it be better to write a function that identifies the vcard URL, generates the file, downloads it and redirects them back to the original team members page?

Any pointers to any resources or a thorough explanation of the best route would be ideal, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the URL being **domain.co.uk/our-team/daniel-vickers/?vcard** instead, I have an idea.

Let's say you have a custom post type called `team_member` and it's URL is /our-team/<name-of-a-post> and then a custom field within that custom post type called `vcard`, then you can add something like this, in your theme's `functions.php`:

```php
function tpl_redir_hook(){
    if(get_post_type() === 'team_member' && isset($_GET['vcard'])){
        header('Content-Type: text/vcard', true);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
        exit(get_field('vcard'));   
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'tpl_redir_hook');
```

Then, **domain.co.uk/our-team/daniel-vickers/** would show a normal page and **domain.co.uk/our-team/daniel-vickers/?vcard** would trigger a download of `daniel-vickers.vcf` and since it's a download, default browser behavior means there's no need to redirect back as you're staying on the **domain.co.uk/our-team/daniel-vickers/** URL.

I use the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook because it's after a post has been found but before anything is output to the page.